Jupyter notebook showing incorrect version of Python in pycharm or vs code
Terminal shows python 3.10.10
Jupyter notebook shows 3.8.19
I am trying to create the new environment with different python version and use pycharm jupyter notebook. I have changed the interpreter and kernel after creating the environment and activating it. The terminal and jupyter notebook showing different python versions.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
